# Rotating Hash for 16 bit

Tags: c, hash

[This site](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/algorithms/jsw_tut_hashing.aspx) gives description of rotating hash as follows.

```
unsigned rot_hash ( void *key, int len )
{
    unsigned char *p = key;
    unsigned h = 0;
    int i;

    for ( i = 0; i < len; i++ )
        h = ( h << 4 ) ^ ( h >> 28 ) ^ p[i];

   return h;
}
```

The returned value is 32 bit here. However, I want to return a 16 bit hash value. For that purpose, is it correct to assign `h` as follows in the loop? Consider `h` to be declared as a 16 bit integer here.

```
for ( i = 0; i < len; i++ )
          h = ( h << 4 ) ^ ( h >> 12 ) ^ p[i];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is probably best to keep the big hash, and only truncate on return, like:

```
for ( i = 0; i < len; i++ )
    h = ( h << 4 ) ^ ( h >> 28 ) ^ p[i];

return h & 0xffff;
```

The shift constants 4 and 28 are probably not the best (in short: because they  have a common divisor)

After some experimentation, I came to the following hashfunction, which is aimed at having maximal entropy in the lower bits (such that a power-of-two table size can be used) (this is the one used in [Wakkerbot](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wakkerbot/)):

```
unsigned hash_mem(void *dat, size_t len)
{
unsigned char *str = (unsigned char*) dat;
unsigned val=0;
size_t idx;

for(idx=0; idx < len; idx++ )   {
        val ^= (val >> 2) ^ (val << 5) ^ (val << 13) ^ str[idx] ^ 0x80001801;
        }
return val;
}
```

The extra perturbance with  0x80001801 is not strictly needed, but helps if the hashed items have long common prefixes. It also helps if these prefixes consist of 0x0 values.

Comment: how should we write a rotating hash method that is independent of number of bits in an array?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to talk about "correct" with hashes, because any deterministic result can be considered correct. Perhaps the hash distribution won't be so good, but this hash doesn't seem like the strongest anyway.

With the change you suggest, the number you'll get will still be a 32 bit number, and the high 16 bits won't be zeros.

The easiest thing to do is change nothing, and cast the result to `unsigned short`.

Comment: Consider I declare h as 16 bit integer.

Comment: You didn't write it in the beginning. Anyway, it's generally better to truncate data as late as possible.